# How to Perform document.write the Highlighted Text in Chrome Extension with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am currently building a simple extension that can retrieve the highlighted text in chrome page and then write down the highlighted text in iframe using following codes:

### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            body {
                width: 400px;
                height: 500px;
            }
            iframe {
                width: 400px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe frameborder="1"></iframe> <!--'1' for border on/ '0' for border off-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
    document.write(selection[0])
});
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "txls_demo",
  "description": "retrieve highlighted text then return the summarized result",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "favicon.png",
    "48": "favicon.png",
    "128": "favicon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

These codes successfully copy the highlighted text and write those on given size of iframe.

However, I'd like to reproduce the same functionality with react.js in chrome extension, thus has tried following codes inside of the `project` dir after perform `npx react create app project`

### manifest.json

```
  "name": "txls_demo",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": "favicon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "version": "1.0"
}
```

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function Iframe(props) {
    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html:  props.iframe?props.iframe:""}} />);
}


const iframe = '<iframe frameborder="1" width="400" height="500"></iframe>';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    get_highlight() {
        /*global chrome*/
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
            code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
        }, function(selection) {
            document.write(selection[0])
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Iframe iframe={iframe} />
                {this.get_highlight()}
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

It builds somehow successfully and renders iframe well with given size, however, fails to copy the highlighted text.

Which modification could solve the problem in most compact way?

Comment: Since the extension API is asynchronous, using document.write makes little sense as the document (the page) is already closed by that time. You should use the standard DOM methods to process and assign some element's innerHTML.

Comment: @wOxxOm but in case of the first version, non-react one, keep writing highlighted text whenever I change the highlighted region and hit the extension favicon. I'd like to know just how to retrieve highlighted text area whenever I hit the favicon not keep automatically tracking the highlighted text area automatically .

Comment: My point is that one should not use document.write here. Actually, its use case is entirely for legacy hacks and quirks.

Comment: @wOxxOm Never use dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Comment: Security-wise I'd also use `sandbox` attribute on the iframe.